# creating folder with date range linux shell or C

Tags: linux, shell, directory, shell-scripting

Hi i need to create a series of folder with a range of date for exmaple

createdir 2010-02-02 2010-02-05

will create :

> 20100202/ 20100203/ 20100204/
>   20100205/

What the best way to do this with a Shell Script or with a C POSIX program?

Comment: Stackoverflow maybe?

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351282/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-dates-given-starting-and-ending-dates-using-awk-of . I like the @camh answwer.

You can create a shell script with this content,

```
#!/bin/bash
#./createdir 2010-02-02 2010-02-05

startdate=$1
enddate=$2

for d in $(seq $(date +%s -d $startdate) +86400 $(date +%s -d $enddate)); do
  mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d -d @$d)
done
```

Comment: ./date_script.sh 2011-01-01 2011-01-02

date: invalid date `@1.29396e+09'
date: invalid date `@1.29387e+09'
Why does that happens?

Comment: This code works in Ubuntu. Sounds like date command don´t understend the date format, YYYY-MM-DD. Try to call date with different date formats, for example, cturiel@menta:~/tmp$ date +%s -d 2010-02-02
1265065200
cturiel@menta:~/tmp$ date +%s -d 20100202
1265065200
cturiel@menta:~/tmp$ date +%s -d 2010/02/02
1265065200